# Mongodb C# with driver 1.9 serialization limited number of parameters?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got a problem during serialization. I already spent lots of time and I cant find a solution. I have a class that I want to serialize to a collection of documents. If I have four properties in my class, everything's great, but as soon as I add another property, I've got this exception :

`An incorrect number of type args were specified for the declaration of a Func type.`

Here is my code :

```
   class Class1
   {
      [BsonId]
      public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

      public string Modelname { get; set; }
      public string Sn { get; set; }
      public string Filename { get; set; }

      public byte[] DataBin { get; set; }
      [BsonIgnore]
      public MyCustomClass data { get; set; }

      [BsonConstructor]
      public Class1()
      { }

      public Class1(string Modelname, string Sn, string Filename, MyCustomClass data)
      {
         this.Modelname = Modelname;
         this.Sn = Sn;
         this.Filename = Filename;
         this.data = data;

         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this.data);
            this.DataBin = stream.ToArray();
         }
      }

      [BsonConstructor]
      public Class1(string Modelname, string Sn, string Filename, byte[] dataBin)
      {
         this.Modelname = Modelname;
         this.Sn = Sn;
         this.Filename = Filename;
         this.DataBin = dataBin;

         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(this.DataBin))
         {
            this.data = (MyCustomClass)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
         }
      }
   }
```

The class Class1 is well serialized in my collection.

```
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
     MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
     MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("mydb");
     MongoCollection<Class1> collection = database.GetCollection<Class1>("testCollection");
     MyCustomClass data = new MyCustomClass();
     Class1 doc = new Class1("test", "sn", "filename", data);
     collection.Save<Class1>(doc);
```

However, if I add another property, the exception is thrown :

```
   class Class1
   {
      [BsonId]
      public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

      public string Modelname { get; set; }
      public string Sn { get; set; }
      public string Filename { get; set; }

      public double Num { get; set; }

      public byte[] DataBin { get; set; }
      [BsonIgnore]
      public MyCustomClass data { get; set; }

      [BsonConstructor]
      public Class1()
      { }

      public Class1(string Modelname, string Sn, string Filename, double Num, MyCustomClass data)
      {
         this.Modelname = Modelname;
         this.Sn = Sn;
         this.Filename = Filename;
         this.Num = Num;
         this.data = data;

         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this.data);
            this.DataBin = stream.ToArray();
         }
      }

      [BsonConstructor]
      public Class1(string Modelname, string Sn, string Filename, double Num, byte[] dataBin)
      {
         this.Modelname = Modelname;
         this.Sn = Sn;
         this.Filename = Filename;
         this.Num = Num;
         this.DataBin = dataBin;

         BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(this.DataBin))
         {
            this.data = (MyCustomClass)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the problem. I tried on the same computer with another solution, and everything was working fine. So I copied the code to my actual solution and it did not work : same code, same computer, but different result ! And finally, I realized that my actual solution used .NET 3.5. I changed it to .NET 4.0 and it works !

Conclusion : the official C# driver is said to been build under .NET 3.5, but it works better under .NET 4.0

Comment: It's cause .NET 3.5 only defines Func delegates with up to 4 parameters.